# Expected 'Py_ssize_t' but got 'long'

Tags: python, scikit-image, superpixels

I'm reimplementing SLIC for Image Segmentation just for fun. But I'm lazy and I do not want to write a function to make all cluster connected so I decide to use `_enforce_label_connectivity_cython()` from skimage but I get an error of Buffer dtype mismatch and I don't now how to solve it

[image].

Comment: What is `boundaries`? Can you provide a complete code sample? It's important to know what the input array types are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of `np.expand_dims(boundaries, axis=0)`, that is, the type of the elements inside the array, is not what the Cython function expects. It expects `Py_ssize_t` which is a type that depends on your platform, but it is getting an array of type `long` which means `np.int64`. To get the right type, I *think* you can do:

```py
labels = _enforce_label_connectivity_cython(
    np.expand_dims(boundaries, axis=0).astype(np.intp),
    min_size,
    max_size,
)
```

If that doesn't work, try `.astype(np.int32)`. Again, the exact answer depends on your OS and Python version, but if I remember correctly, `np.intp` should be the correct type to match `Py_ssize_t`.

Comment: Thanks `.astype(np.intp)` solve the error. I was focused on min_size & max_size and I have not considered that the error was on by the first parameter